# Debugging CSS for Internet Explorer Compatability View

Tags: css, debugging, internet-explorer

I am using CSS to show and hide a nested UL to simulate a dropdown navigation without js. 
It looks and works great in most browsers with the exception of some versions of IE. I've been beating my head against the wall four almost the entire day trying to find the solution for this, trying what I believe to be every combination of solutions. If anyone else has a suggestion, I would love to hear it.

**The Problem:**
When you hover on the main navigation a UL appears(left:0; on hover). The List items do not have a background color so you overlay an existing navigation and you can see both at the same time.

[See Here](http://entrec.elearningstudents.ca/about/)

If anyone can explain this behaviour I would welcome any help or insight at this point. The release site goes to the client tonight and I really it to be good.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

set li ul initially to display none; then on li:hover ul{display:block}....that may not work with how you have them absolutely positioned, but that's the easiest way to hide/show with css. i see what you mean about them overlaying each other. you could also try adding a class to each sub ul, and targeting each directly, so instead of li:hover ul blanketing them all, you'd have li.first:hover ul.subfirst{positioning css}.